# meaning of mshkg000019.blob.core.windows.net in Client Hello packet in ssl

Tags: ios, ssl, azure-storage, icloud, azure-blob-storage

I have captured some pcap files for icloud traffic. I have seen some ssl flows which will have either of following server names in the Client Hello packet

```
mshkg000019.blob.core.windows.net
mshkg000018.blob.core.windows.net
mshkg000015.blob.core.windows.net
```

Can anyone please let me know the meaning of "mshkg000019" here ? What does "mshkg" means here and what does the different numbers like 19,18,15 signify here ? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these are the server names that are being sent as part of the TLS server name extension.

"mskhg" does not mean anything, it's just the server name that your client is trying to connect to. You should read more about server name indication TLS extension http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Comment: yeah correct, this indicated the server to which client tries to connect, but i would like to know the meaning of these fields "mshkg" & "000019" etc. Whether these are specific to "icloud" or "username" or anything else ? For eg, in case of http the general format is *http://<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<blob>* . similarly i want to know the meaning in case of server name in ssl client hello.